# Using a Snapshot View

Tags: ios

The apple documentation suggests that I can use a snapshot view to conceal drawing operations. I have a sequence of steps that look jumpy. I would like to make all the updates then display them all at once. I have tried to hide the updates using variations on

```
UIView *snapshot = [scrollView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO] ;  //YES/NO makes no difference.
[mainView addSubview:snapshot] ;


// Do updates


[snapshot removeFromSuperview] ; // Ideally animate the transition.
```

The problem I have is that the snapshot never appears. All the screen update gyrations appear on the screen just as though I never tried to display the snapshot.

If I delete the removeFromSuperview, I can see that the snapshot is successfully created and displays (before the gyrations).

IOS clearly is optimizing the updates to my detriment.

1) Do I have the wrong approach to hiding updates (scrolling, image draws)?
2) If so, what should I be trying?
3) If not, what do I need to do to ensure the changes take place behind the snapshot?

I find it frustrating that IOS optimizes my snapshot out but does not optimize the screen changes.

Comment: It's hard to know why removeFromSuperview would be executed before what happens in "Do updates" without seeing the code you're using there.

Comment: Using transitionFromView forces the snapshot to being visible.